# values as set by a random integer method are not persisting for later methods (beginner java)

Tags: java

I have written two methods which return the median value of an integer array containing three elements. As I understand, the methods are functioning as intended.

I have subsequently tried to code the testing of these methods in the main method in the following way:

1) declare/initialize elements of array
2) randomize these values
3) execute a syso statement which contains the method where the method returns an integer value
4) repeat step #2
5) repeat step #3 with the second method to be tested.

**Question: Why am i seeing integer values of 0 in the print statements instead of the median values of a randomized 3 element array instead?**

source code as follows (please ignore the German language):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Median {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;

        randABC(a,b,c);
        System.out.println("Der durch den Median berechnete Medianwert ist: " + median(a, b, c));
        randABC(a,b,c);
        System.out.println("Der durch den Median2 berechnete Medianwert ist: " + median2(a, b, c));

    }

    public static int median(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int[] iA = {a,b,c}; // iA = integer Array
        gnomeSort(iA);
        return iA[1];   
    }

    public static int median2(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int[] iA = {a,b,c}; // iA = integer Array
        selectionSort(iA);
        return iA[1];   
    }


    public static void gnomeSort(int iA[])
    {
        int i = 1;
        int n = iA.length;

        while (i < n)
        {
            if (i == 0 || iA[i - 1] <= iA[i])
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                int temp = iA[i];
                iA[i] = iA[i - 1];
                iA[--i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void selectionSort(int iA[])
    {
        int i, j; 
        int n = iA.length;

        for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++) 
        {
            int iMin = j;
            for (i = j+1; i < n; i++) 
            {
                if (iA[i] < iA[iMin]) 
                {
                    iMin = i;
                }   
            }

            if (iMin != j)
            {

                int temp = iA[j];
                iA[j] = iA[iMin];
                iA[iMin] = temp;

            }   

        }

    }

    public static void randABC(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        a = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
        b = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
        c = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
        System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ", c = " + c);
    }

}
```

sample console output:

```
a = 648, b = 405, c = 687
Der durch den Median1 berechnete Medianwert ist: 0
a = 998, b = 587, c = 931
Der durch den Median1 berechnete Medianwert ist: 0
```

Comment: Java is _not_ pass-by-reference, i.e. the values of `a`, `b` and `c` in your main method are not changed.

Comment: `a`, `b`, and `c` are *inputs* to your function `randABC`, not *outputs*. to have an output you must specify a return type and return a value. if you need to return multiple values then you need to encapsulate them in a separate class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `int` values are primitive values. This means, among other things, that everytime you pass an `int` from one place to another, you make a copy of it's value (this is known as pass-by-value).

So for instance, when you pass a, b, and c to `randABC`, those are merely copies of those variables, and as such `randABC` cannot actually modify the original variables, because the a, b, and c parameters of `randABC` are different variables from the a, b, and c in your `main` method. So even after calling `randABC`, the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` remain unchanged.

The only way to modify an int value is to directly put it on the left side of an assignment `=`. A version that would actually work would be

```
public static void random3()
{
    int a = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
    int b = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
    int c = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
    System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ", c = " + c);

    return new int[]{a, b, c};
}
```

Then your `main` becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int random[] = random3();
    int a = random[0];
    int b = random[1];
    int c = random[2];
    System.out.println("Der durch den Median berechnete Medianwert ist: " 
                        + median(a, b, c));

    random[] = random3();
    a = random[0];
    b = random[1];
    c = random[2];
    System.out.println("Der durch den Median2 berechnete Medianwert ist: "
                        + median2(a, b, c));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because variables a, b and c which you changes in `randABC` and a, b, c from main are different fields. In java field lifetime is limited by scopes. So after you passing variables, method doesn't know what are they you just declare that these are three int values. You changes them in the method somehow. And after method ends its work GC removes them from heap. So in a nutshell: abc from main and abc from `randABC()` are different fields.

You should improve randABC:

```
public static int[] randABC()
{
    int a = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
    int b = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
    int c = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
    System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ", c = " + c);
    return new int[]{a, b, c};
}
```

and invoke it this way:

```
int[] arr = randABC(a, b, c);
```

Then you can pass a, b, c to other methods like `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]`.